# Django taggit form label

Tags: python, django

I've found a solution to render tags registered in taggit models as choices list  by doing:

```
from taggit.models import Tag
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
```

(i changed something in taggit folder i guess, .... i forgot but i works without any problem )

but i would like to change label name ("Tags" by default)

i tried in  forms.py:

```
imports ...
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag = [(i, i) for i in Tag.objects.all()]
    tags = forms.ChoiceField(label='another label name', choices=tag )
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('tags',)
```

it shows the result i expected but when i save or POST it return a form validation error 'Cannot assign "u'tag name'": "BlogPost.tags" must be a "Tag" instance.'

so can someone handle this and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `pk` as key

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    tag = [(i.pk, i.title) for i in Tag.objects.all()]
    #     ^^^^^
    tags = forms.ChoiceField(label='another label name', choices=tag )
```

and may be better solution is to use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)

```
     tags = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tag.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
```

Comment: tag does not have title ( maybe because of my modification) but the second one works thanks

Comment: glad to help you, title was as example it need to change on your column name.